# Saving VBA code within Powerpoint embedded Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint-2010

The VBA created in an Excel sheet that is embedded in a Powepoint presentation is not saved.

I have a Powerpoint file, in which I have Inserted a Chart, thus creating an embedded Excel Workbook.

I have tried adding some VBA to said embedded Excel Workbook. IT all worked fine and my VBA worked as expected.

Until I closed the embedded Excel file and tried reopening it (by right clicking on the Powerpoint Chart and clicking on Edit Data). After reopening it, all of my VB was gone.

I suspect it has something to do with the embedded Excel file not being Macro enabled, but I can't figure out how to change this.

(Happy to provide a sample file if required)

Comment: If you insert a XLS object the Macro are NOT saved. If you insert a XLSM object, the macro ARE saved, and work...

Comment: This is going to sound insane, but how do you insert either? 
The embedded Excel sheet I'm talking about is created when I insert a chart within Powerpoint. 
If I insert an Excel file (XLS or XLSM) as an object, it either shows as an icon or a part of the worksheet, neither of which I want.

Comment: To Insert, only Drag and Drop (is embedded)... You can first create a XLSM files, Drag&Drop, use / modify and delete the original XLSM and keep pptx.